# Open Source PHP Mail Script not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email

I am working on a website, and I don't like to write mail scripts again and again. I am trying this Javascript:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#button").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var arr=createDomString($("#contactForm"));
console.log(arr);
//var data=createDomArray($("#contactForm"));

$.ajax({

    type:'POST',
    url:'php/mailer.php',
    data:"datastring="+arr,
    //datatype:"json",
    success: function(d){           
        console.log("php response "+d);
    }           

});
});

});

</script>
```

However, I get this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: createDomString is not defined
```

Is there a problem with the script or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mailer.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure to include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mailer.js"></script>
```

createDOMString is defined in there, so i can safely assume that it is not included in your script ;)

Comment: Is it necessary to include? Some other way to get it working?

Comment: createDomString function is define in mailer.js file